# Como puedo Optimizar mi servidor - tengo instalado Odoo 9

Tags: odoo

Tengo mi sitio web en `Odoo 9`, el tráfico diario un promedio 40 personas más 10 usuarios internos, tengo varios módulos instalados para manejar ventas, compras, contabilidad etc.

Tengo mi servidor en Digital Ocean, mi configuracion es:

Hardware:

- Ubuntu 14
- 8 Gb RAM
- 4 CPU

Configuracion de software
**Ngnix**

- Tengo postgres
- Tengo habilitada la memoria de intercambio
- SWAP Tengo optimizadas las imagenes, JavaScript, HTML, SQL, etc

Aveces el servidor es muy lento, pero no se muy bien cual es el problema real, me podrian dar por favor alguna Pista

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola @john, esta pregunta creo que va más relacionada con sistemas que con programación. Quizás deberías preguntarla (en inglés) en el portal de Ubuntu de stackexchange ya que seguramente ellos te puedan proporcionar métodos más específicos para saber que puede fallar.

Comment: Con lento, a que te refieres? Puede ser tu configuración del Nginx, yo tengo un servidor local entro mediante dyndns, y funciona perfecto incluso es de menores características "para el servidor que tu tienes... es demasiado para odoo" yo solo encuentro problemas cuando hago algun cambio importante y se cuelga "aplicar updates, modificar modulos, vistas, cargar todo el inventario.

Comment: Hola que tal, lo solucione comprando un buen servidor dedicado en OVH y configurando Odoo de manera correcta, luego de tanto investigar logre llegar al resultado que necesitaba. Saludos